# Getting different results for the same equation in a function and the shell

Tags: ipython, sage, modular-arithmetic

I've implemented Pollard's Rho for logarithms using Sage, as the following program stored in `pollardrho.py`.

```
def pollardrho(g, h, G):
    k, m = 1, 0
    t = g**k * h**m
    i, j = 1, 0
    r = g**i * h**j

    def step(t, k, m):
        if lift(t) % 3 == 0:
            return (t * g, k+1, m)
        if lift(t) % 3 == 1:
            return (t * h, k, m+1)
        if lift(t) % 3 == 2:
            return (t ** 2, 2*k, 2*m)

    while True:
        t, k, m = step(t, k, m)
        r, i, j = step(*step(r, i, j))
        if t == r:
            print("Found a cycle")
            print("g^%s h^%s == g^%s h^%s" % (k, m, i, j))
            print("g^(%s - %s) == h^(%s - %s)" % (i, k, m, j))
            l = g.multiplicative_order()
            print("(%s - %s) / (%s - %s) %% %s" % (i, k, m, j, l))
            return (i - k) / (m - j) % l  # this is where everything goes wrong.
```

Running this with `G = GF(1013), g = G(3), h = G(245)` gives the following output:

```
sage: pollardrho(g, h, G)
Found a cycle
g^262 h^14 == g^16870 h^1006
g^(16870 - 262) == h^(14 - 1006)
(16870 - 262) / (14 - 1006) % 1012
995
```

However:

```
sage: (16870 - 262) / (14 - 1006) % 1012
375
```

Note that this is a completely different result!

If I check the types of `i, j, k, m`, they are all of type `int`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that typing an integer in the sage shell gives a different result than doing the same inside a python program that uses Sage libraries:

```
sage: type(1234)
<type 'sage.rings.integer.Integer'>
```

This isn't the same as the `<type 'int'>` I got inside of my own program!

Using `k, m = Integer(1), Integer(0)` solved my problem and I now get the correct discrete log.

Comment: Yup!  That is absolutely correct.  I'll give a followup as an answer so people see it.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Thom's answer, in a `.py` file you can't use the various preparsing things that Sage does - in particular, `int`s are `int`s.  Importing from `sage.rings.integer.Integer` (or from `sage.all`) in your file could work, or (and I recommend this) just making your file `.sage` extension instead of `.py` is the easiest, and least likely to run into other subtle differences.

Comment: Do `.sage` files still work with 'from x import y' or do I need to use `load()` in that case?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question. I assume the answer is `load()` since I've never done anything else (and it's easier for me), but since the `.sage` file is then preparsed into a `.py` file I suppose it's possible that works too, if you've created some module.  Try it and see!

Comment: Since I'm now at a computer instead of on my phone I've been able to test it, it doesn't appear to work. So that's one unfortunate downside.

Comment: For completeness, doing `load('pollardrho.py')` also doesn't replace ints by `Integer`, while `load('pollardrho.sage')` does. So it's not just the `import` statement that doesn't do magic, it really does depend on the file extension.